# WordPress needs the FTP credentials to update plugins

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

I host WordPress on **AWS EC2 ([Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29))** and encounter the following error while updating plugins:

> To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

`rwx` permission has been granted to the user `www-data`. Here is what I do.

```
<!– language: lang-bash –>

# Add a new group
groupadd www-pub

# Add the user `www-data` to the group 'www-pub'
usermod -a -G www-pub www-data

# Change the ownership of '/var/www/' to 'ubuntu:www-pub'
chown -R ubuntu:www-pub /var/www

# Change the permissions of all the folders to 2775
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +

# Change the permissions of all the files to 0664
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

As you can see, `www-data` has all the right permissions, but I am still required to enter the FTP credentials. What is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: The best way that I have found to do this is with Google Chrome or Firefox is to download the plugin: LastPass and it will fill in the login/password for you.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Leptonator, no. `wordpress` requires to login in ftp with **password** but AWS EC2 provides me **SSH-keys**. I know that creating a password for ftp is a solution but I don't think this way is a good one.

Comment: Have you tried adding `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` to your wp-config.php file?

Comment: @Brandon yeah, I put it in the end of `wp-config.php` and it doesn't work. As @Corlax suggested, put it below the database information and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a simple fix. Just edit file *wp-config.php* and write this code inside it.

First try this:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Note: Do not add this to the end of the file, but just below the database information on the top of the file.

```
define('FTP_USER', 'username'); // Your FTP username
define('FTP_PASS', 'password'); // Your FTP password
define('FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21'); // Your FTP URL:Your FTP port
```

Also please read [this blog post](http://www.white.guru/2012/05/how-to-set-up-wordpress-on-amazon-ec2_31.html).

Comment: thx, it works for me. A couple of weeks ago, I put `define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');` in the end of the file `wp-config.php`, which  doesn't work.

Comment: I'd consider this answer a work around. The answer to change the ownership of the files to www-data:www-data, provided by mtinsley, fixes the underlying issue.

Answer (score 7):

This means that WordPress is having limited permission for making changes in the folder that it was installed.

In-order to fix this, all that you need to do is provide necessary permissions for the same.

Run the following command in your terminal, [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), or command line prompt after connecting to your Server via SSH.

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
```

Checkout the below article for full details (Syam | MMWYS.Online):

*[How to fix the infamous issue of WordPress asking for FTP Credentials for Installing Plugins / Themes?](http://mmwys.online/2016/08/04/how-to-fix-the-infamous-issue-of-wordpress-asking-for-ftp-credentials-for-installing-plugins-themes/)*

Comment: The link leads to a splash page with ads on it. Perhaps the hosting has been suspended...

Comment: The link seems to be broken. There is an apparently dubious redirect to `find.runquestrun.com`. See for example *[Eliminate Runquestrun.com redirect trojan (uninstall instructions)](https://www.anti-malware.name/removal-guide/remove-runquestrun-com/)*

Comment: Or is Runquestrun.com (also) a Windows executable?...

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/168428/linux-group-permissions-not-being-enforced-correctly) explains why it isn't working.

Most Ubuntu web servers I have seen are set up a bit differently from what you're doing. I'm not sure what your reason is for doing it that way, but if you wanted to keep things simple you would just set the owner and group for all files to `www-data`:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

That will grant the web server full access to all of your files in the web root. If you needed to grant any additional users access to those files, you would just add them to the `www-data` group.

```
usermod -a -G www-data someuser
```

The file permissions you've set up look good to me as-is.

```
#Change the permissions of all the folders to 2775
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +

#Change the permissions of all the files to 0664
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

For reference, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/what-is-the-first-chmod-octal-digit-in-a-four-digit-value-for) explains what `chmod 2775` (specifically the 2) means.

Essentially, it causes any new files to inherit the group of the directory. `www-data` in this case. This means the web server will have access to any files created by other users, without having to change the ownership or permissions of those files.

Comment: The answer you mentioned, `When adding a user to a new group, that won't be applied in any currently-running processes, only new ones. You need to log out and then log back in.`, couldn't explain it because I restart apache2.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a user to your project.

#### For NGINX Servers:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R <your_wordpress_dir>
```

#### For Apache Servers:

```
sudo chown apache:apache -R <your_wordpress_dir>
```

And change directory permissions:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R <your_wordpress_dir>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line `define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );` of code in your `wp-config.php` file after `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`.

So it should be like this:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Save the file and try again.